# Javascript or XUL windows WITHOUT iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, xul

I am trying to build a multi-window website for my bookmarks, but I have some problems.

Here is the js version of what I am trying to build:
http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/zpwin/zapatec

Unfortunately, there are problems with this approach. The sites in the windows are loaded through iframes, and iframes have problems (like framebreaker sites and js issues).

I want them to be XUL browsers or anything without iframe. Do you think this is possible? If so, how?

My main target is to make a website that people login and see their bookmarks like the one on the example. I don't want a firefox extension. I want something similar to www.only2clicks.com but showing the actual websites, not the thumbnails.

I am open to other approaches. Maybe flex or stuff.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do efficiently here. You would essentially be making a proxy if you fetch all of the data of a page then display it on your site using your server. And that can be tough on the server. Iframes are the best approach here if you want to display a working website in their place. Perhaps thumbnails are a better option.

Comment: I don't want any "server side includes". I don't want thumbnails. You may check this out : http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_splitbrowser.html.en

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to load a web site in a tiny iframe like that. You can't use the sites when they're that small.

Have you ever used the [Opera browser](http://www.opera.com)? That might be a better solution to your problem - you can save sessions (groups of web pages) and you can also tile the tabs.

Comment: I hate tabs. You can't see more than 1 website at the same time, which is a must for many people. This way of surfing is my favourite - Maximize, surf, minimize. I hate typing.

Comment: Note the part **"you can also tile the tabs"**. You can make Opera look almost exactly like the page you set up (you may have to turn an option on to do it).